# Why RISC-V Assembly Error: Runtime Exception - Address Out of Range?

Tags: exception, assembly, riscv

Code:

assembly
Copy code

```
.data
ask1: .string "Please enter a number to compute its factorial value:   "
msg: .string "The result is: %d\n"  # Format for the result

.text
.globl main

main:
    la a0, ask1
    li a7, 4
    ecall

    li a7, 5
    ecall

    jal ra, Factorial
    mv a0, a1  # Move the result to a0 for printf
    j printResult

Factorial:
    beqz a0, returnFactorial
    addi sp, sp, -8
    sw ra, 4(sp)
    sw a0, 0(sp)
    addi a0, a0, -1
    jal ra, Factorial
    lw a1, 0(sp)
    addi sp, sp, 8
    mul a1, a1, a0
    lw ra, 4(sp)
    jr ra

returnFactorial:
    addi a0, x0, 1
    jr ra

printResult:
    .include "printf.s"
    jal ra, printf

    li a0, 0
    ecall
```

Any assistance or insights into resolving this error would be greatly appreciated

I encountered a runtime exception while working on RISC-V assembly code, and I'm seeking assistance in resolving it. The error specifically mentions an address out of range (0x00000004). I've been attempting to calculate the factorial of a number and print the result using the printf function from an external file (printf.s).

Answer (score 1):

You've unbalanced the stack, by doing the `addi sp, sp, 8` too soon.

You want the `lw ra, 4(sp)`, for example, to load using the same exact memory location as the original `sw ra, 4(sp)`, so this means you have to wait to do the `addi sp, sp, 8` until you've finished reloading `ra`.

Logically speaking, you can see that you have to keep `sp` the same or else those addressing modes — `4(sp)` in `lw` and `4(sp)` in `sw` — won't refer to the same exact memory address.

(Technically, since you know you're adjusting the stack by +8, you could offset the `lw` by by -8, so `lw ra, -4(sp)`, but this is bad practice (you'll not see a compiler do that) because this relies on memory that has technically be released, and that can be a problem on several different systems — a short window (2 instructions or so) during which an interrupt could wipe out what's below the stack pointer, and if you do the stack space release in the proper place, there is no such window of vulnerability.)

---

You are returning the value from function `factorial` in `a1`.  It is ok to deviate from the standard calling convention when you know what your doing and why, though in case you're trying to follow the standard, you would return the value in `a0` instead.

Easy change to make by having the `mul` target `a0`, and the caller expecting the return value in `a0` instead of `a1`.

And I would say that you need to make this change because your `lw a1, 0(sp)`, upon return from the recursive call, is otherwise wiping out the return value in `a1`.

---

Not sure your parameter passing to `printf` is correct — if it is a normal printf, then you have to pass a format string in `a0` and the value in `a1`, but if it is simply a print_int then looks ok.

Also, might want to check your exit code `ecall` sequence — need to put something into `a7` for `ecall`.